# Android: Cut off constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

When adding a constraint layout within another constraint layout the inner one gets cut off.
I already tried changing the constraint top of view but that didn't change anything. Anyone knows why this is happening?

I also tried it out with different layouts ( the cyan one is the culprit ) which all had the same effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyberpunk_background"
    tools:context=".Todo_create">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/square_round"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_round"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_round"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_todo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_round"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/alarm_clock_1" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: It is not obvious why you think your `ConstraintLayout` is being cut off. The only child of it appears to be shown clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an unnecessary `android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"` in your nested constraint layout.

Comment: Yeah apparently using the constraints for sizing the elements with the 0dp width and height is extremely buggy. Thanks! Just set the height manually and now it works.